# Поиск по наличию одного из нескольких значений

Tags: javascript, поиск

Как сделать поиск по наличию хотя бы одного из нескольких значений в строке в JavsScript?

Пробовал следующие:

```
let someString = "123+456-789*0"
if(someString.includes('a' || 'b' || '*' || '/')) { console.log(true) }
```

другой вариант

```
if(someString.indexOf('a' || 'b' || '*' || '/') > 0) { console.log(true) }
```

Или придется использовать циклы? Спасибо.

Comment: А вот это `'a' || 'b' || '*' || '/'` вообще бред полный!   Что в твоём контекста означает 'a' или если она undefined то 'b' или если обе undefined то '*' По сути 'a' некогда не undefined и вернёт 100% только 'a'

Comment: @EugeneX Во первых тут агрессия ни к чему. А во вторых Логическое ИЛИ не работает то как вы описали

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А может быть просто

```
if (/[ab*/]/.test(someString))
```

?